# Upload and download document file to SharePoint site

Tags: office365, onedrive, sharepoint-online, office365-restapi

We are developing one tool which will monitor Office365 services.

In between as per requirement, I have to check time required to upload and download document file to particular SharePoint site. I have tried by using java, but I was not able to do this.

Please suggest me which technology would be better for me to do this and suggest me solutions if any.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OneDrive API is a part of the Microsoft Graph suite of services, documented here http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/.

If you have more flexibility in your platform, [OneDrive has SDKs](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/code-samples-and-sdks) available for C# which might be more intune with your needs   There is also a Android SDK would could be a starting point for your own java library.

OneDrive has a [specific documentation site](https://dev.onedrive.com/) for writing a REST client against its service, which could be of use for writing a Java library.